# GET_ACCOUNT permission is not granted in android N

Tags: android, android-7.0-nougat, runtime-permissions

I am working on Account manager. I want to check account is exists or not.

```
 private static final String TAG = "UserAccountUtil";

    public static Account getAccount(Context context) {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, android.Manifest.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Log.d(TAG, "GET_ACCOUNTS not present.");

        }

        AccountManager accountManager = AccountManager.get(context);
        Account[] accounts = accountManager.getAccountsByType(Constant.ACCOUNT_TYPE);
        if (accounts.length > 0) {
            Log.d(TAG, "GET_ACCOUNTS  present..."+accounts[0]);
            return accounts[0];
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "GET_ACCOUNTS not  present...");

            return null;
        }
    }
```

It always returns null or "GET_ACCOUNTS not present." in logs. I have added in manifest also.I am asking for run time permission also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [**`GET_ACCOUNTS`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#GET_ACCOUNTS)--> Beginning with Android 6.0 (API level 23), if an app shares the
>   signature of the authenticator that manages an account, it does not
>   need "GET_ACCOUNTS" permission to read information about that account.
>   On Android 5.1 and lower, all apps need "GET_ACCOUNTS" permission to
>   read information about any account.The GET_ACCOUNTS permission is now **<s>Dead</s>**

You can use **`READ_CONTACTS`** permission instead of.

- Check to **`Build.VERSION.SDK_INT`**

**DEMO**

```
if (accounts.length > 0 && android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT<23 ) {
            Log.d(TAG, "GET_ACCOUNTS  present..."+accounts[0]);
            return accounts[0];
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "GET_ACCOUNTS not  present...");

            return null;
        }
```

Comment: I have added all permission   Manifest.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS,
                        Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE,
                        Manifest.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW,
                        Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS,
                        Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE,

Comment: @PriyadarshiniMaurya Solved this yet?